# Deleting a file from a sub directory of an AWS S3 bucket using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I want to delete a file that resides on the path: **bucket1/dir1/dir2/file.png**

The code I have done:

```
public bool DeleteFileFromS3(string bucketName, string directoryInBucket, string subDirectoryInDirectory, string fileNameInS3) 
{
    IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast2);
    var BucketName = "";

    if (directoryInBucket == "" || directoryInBucket == null)
    {
        BucketName = bucketName; //no subdirectory just bucket name  
    }
    else
    {   // subdirectory and bucket name  
        BucketName = bucketName + @"/" + directoryInBucket + @"/" + subDirectoryInDirectory;
    }

    var objectName = fileNameInS3;

    client.DeleteObject(BucketName, objectName); 

    return true; //indicate that the file was sent 
}
```

However, this doesn't work.

Upon some research, I found out that the AWS file system is different. It is object-based and the files are stored as objects with keys. However, I am unable to find an example that uses keys for a file that resides in the subdirectory of a bucket and then deletes it using them. Kindly suggest me something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BucketName` should only contain the name of the bucket.

The `ObjectName` should include the name of the object, **with the full path to the object**.

For example:

- `BucketName = 'my-bucket'`
- `ObjectName = 'invoices/january/foo.txt'`

This is because Amazon S3 doesn't really have directories, even though it 'appears' to have them. The full path is part of the object name ('Key').

Comment: did it worked. Could you share the code